# Unable to update parameters to Dataflow batch job with custom template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parameter-passing, google-cloud-dataflow

Here is my code

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery import WriteToBigQuery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
import argparse
from apache_beam.transforms.sql import SqlTransform
import datetime as dt
import logging
import re
import json
from datetime import datetime
import time
import bson
from google.cloud import secretmanager
import pymongo

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  
class MyOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--db', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--dbCSKey', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--collectionName', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--clientId', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--projectId', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--bigQuerySchema', required=True)
        parser.add_argument('--secretName', required=True)


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
my_options = pipeline_options.view_as(MyOptions)
    
# Define the pipeline
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
            
    db = my_options.db
    dbCSKey = my_options.dbCSKey
    collectionName = my_options.collectionName
    clientId = my_options.clientId
    projectId = my_options.projectId
    bigQuerySchema = my_options.bigQuerySchema
    secretName = my_options.secretName
    
    bigQueryTable = f'{projectId}:{bigQuerySchema}.{collectionName}'
    
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={'name': secretName})
    secrets = response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')
    secretDict = json.loads(secrets)
    mongoURI = next((tenant['connectionString'] for tenant in secretDict['tenants'] if tenant['clientId'] == dbCSKey), None)

    # Read data from MongoDB
    # mongo_data = (
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoURI)
    db = client[db]
    collection = db[collectionName]

    # Create a PCollection from the MongoDB cursor
    mongo_data = p | 'Read from MongoDB' >> beam.Create(collection.find())
```

The way I create the custom template is as follows

```
python3 -m data-sync --region us-west1 --runner DataflowRunner --project datalake-dev-358216 --temp_location gs://datalake-dev-358216.appspot.com/temp --template_location gs://datalake-dev-358216.appspot.com/template --db=insurance_014_dev --dbCSKey=metlife --collectionName=insurance_claim_procedures --clientId=metlife --projectId=datalake-dev-358216 --bigQuerySchema=ml_data_marts --secretName=projects/762809992414/secrets/mongo-multi-tenant-secret/versions/latest --job_name data-sync-client-insurance-claim-procedures-initial-load
```

The way I am launching this custom template with updated parameters:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run data-sync-initial-load-humana-insurance-claim-procedures-20230612040559 --gcs-location gs://datalake-dev-358216.appspot.com/template --parameters db=insurance_010_dev,dbCSKey=humana,collectionName=insurance_claim_procedures,clientId=humana,projectId=datalake-dev-358216,bigQuerySchema=ml_data_marts,secretName=projects/762809992414/secrets/mongo-multi-tenant-secret/versions/latest,job_name=data-sync-initial-load-humana-insurance-claim-procedures-20230612040559
```

It launches the job with those parameter values that were set while creating the template, whereas, it should override those default values with what I am passing while launching.

I have tried lots of documentation, forums, and chatbots, but so far no solution is found. Please help in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. Have you tried other ways from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates? I also suggest you open a cloud support ticket if possible.